# Tim Newsham format string exploit

Tags: c, security, exploit, format-string

I was reading [Tim Newsham's white paper](https://seclists.org/bugtraq/2000/Sep/214) on format string exploits and found some parts in the beginning difficult to understand.

The following program was being discussed.

```
/*
 * fmtme.c
 *       Format a value into a fixed-size buffer
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[100];
    int x;
    if(argc != 2)
        exit(1);
    x = 1;
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, argv[1]);
    buf[sizeof buf - 1] = 0;
    printf("buffer (%d): %s\n", strlen(buf), buf);
    printf("x is %d/%#x (@ %p)\n", x, x, &x);
    return 0;
}
```

Author says "All examples in this document were actually performed on an x86 BSD/OS 4.1", a little-endian machine.

The program is executed like

```
% ./fmtme "%x %x %x %x"
buffer (15): 1 f31 1031 3133
x is 1/0x1 (@ 0x804745c)
```

The paper says:

```
"A quick analysis of the program will reveal that the stack layout of the
program when the snprintf function is called is:

    Address  Contents       Description
    fp+8     Buffer         pointer 4-byte address
    fp+12    Buffer         length 4-byte integer
    fp+16    Format         string 4-byte address
    fp+20    Variable x     4-byte integer
    fp+24    Variable buf   100 characters

The four values output in the previous test were the next four arguments on
the stack after the format string: the variable x, then three 4-byte
integers
taken from the uninitialized buf variable."
```

What is `fp` here? File pointer?

And why does it start from fp+8 and not fp+4 when the increments are by 4 everwhere else (4-byte address)?

Here, does larger address mean the value is higher up or lower down the stack?

What does the names given under 'Contents' mean?

---

And when I run the above program, the value of `x`, ie, `1`, is not being printed. Maybe because of different architecture?

I get like this

```
./fmtme "%x %x %x %x"
buffer (34): cd512860 b3356d80 b3356d80 8247ee8
x is 1/0x1 (@ 0x7ffc08247d8c)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Frame pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#FRAME-POINTER).

Comment: @user3386109 Can we somehow relate the old to new architectures? If that's what is different?

Answer (score 2):

- `fp` stands for "frame pointer".
- The arguments start at `fp+8`because `fp+4` is the return address and `fp+0` is the saved frame pointer.
- In a conventional grows-down stack as x86 uses, higher addresses are deeper in the stack (items that were pushed earlier).

The `Contents` is a little bit unclear - it's trying to describe what's in that stack slot but some of them don't have names.  This might be clearer:

```
Address  Contents                  Description
fp+8     First snprintf argument   pointer 4-byte address
fp+12    Second snprintf argument  length 4-byte integer
fp+16    Third snprintf argument   string 4-byte address
fp+20    Variable x in main        4-byte integer
fp+24    Variable buf in main      100 characters
```

You don't see the same result because these kinds of things - formally *undefined behaviour* - are highly sensitive to the architecture, compiler and compiler version you're using.  It appears from the pointer value printed with `%p` that you're using a 64 bit architecture - if you're using x86-64, then then first 6 integral arguments to a function are passed in registers, not on the stack, so that's where your bogus `%x` formats are going to start looking.  You could try compiling for x86 with the `-m32` compiler option, but there's no guarantees.

Comment: I'm a novice at architecture concepts. How were you able to figure out that I was using a 64-bit architecture machine from the addresses printed with `%p`?

Comment: I find it a bit strange that the arguments to `snprintf()` are push right-to-left. If more arguments would have been given they would appear between "Format" and "Variable x" by that behaviour. But why does `snprintf()` read "Buffer" and following? That does not match. I suspect here an error by the author.

Comment: @J...S: Because the pointer value printed has more than 32 bits (and I also recognise it as being in the typical range of stack addresses on Linux x86-64).

Comment: @thebusybee: Pushing arguments right-to-left is very common.  This means you can access all the arguments in a varargs function without having to know how many of them there are (because the first argument is always at a known offset from the stack pointer on function entry, just after the return address).

Comment: @thebusybee: [This example](https://godbolt.org/z/So964V) demonstrates pretty clearly right-to-left pushing of arguments.

Comment: @thebusybee Why did you delete your answer? The two answers complemented each other. And I didn't even get to see the reply to my comment.

Comment: Again you're right! I should have thought a moment longer before commenting, and answering. ;-)

Comment: @J...S The longer I looked at it the worse it seemed. In contrary this answer has all the bits right. As caf notes the example depends on *undefined behaviour* and so you don't see the value of `x` printed in the buffer when arguments are passed in registers. I just tried a lot without good results; but my system here at work (to which I have to return right now) is Win10 with MinGW64. If you're curious about the inner workings I'd recommend to go to the URL caf wrote in a comment, look at the assembly code, and experiment. You can do this on your machine, too, by passing `-S` to GCC.

Comment: @thebusybee Yeah, I now used gcc with `-S` (and `-m32`). Thanks.

Comment: @caf Thanks for the assembly code. In it, a value is subtracted from `esp` before pushing the arguments of `foo()`. At first I figured it was to modify the stack pointer after pushing return address or something but the value that is added (back?) to `esp` after `call foo` is different. Any idea why it is so?

Comment: @J...S: It's just allocating some stack space that it doesn't end up using - it's not elided because it's not a fully optimised build.  The value added back in the function epilogue is the 24 subtracted in the prologue plus the 5*4 = 20 used by the 5 pushes.